# Possibility to retrieve BIP39 mnemonic (24 words English dict) from BIP39 (hex) seed?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, seed

I am in a situation where I have access to a BIP39 hex seed which I know has been derived from a BIP39 24 word English dictionary mnemonic.

I would like to retrieve this 24 word list - is this possible?
As far as I know there is no hierarchy per se between hex seed and mnemonic, so they should be bijective (hopefully).

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible.

The seed words are converted to the hex seed through a process involving a one way hashing operation - it is not possible to go the other way.

That said, as long as your hex seed is the tree root, keeping that safely would allow you to access all your coins, although it would make importing it into a wallet somewhat difficult.